# Ionic serve suddenly aborting

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, command-line-interface, ionic3

When trying to run `ionic serve`, the execution suddenly aborts after starting Webpack. Anyone got an idea on what's going on?

```
michaels-macbook-pro:ionic-app michael$ ionic serve
Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 - Ctrl+C to cancel
[13:56:46]  watch started ... 
[13:56:46]  build dev started ... 
[13:56:46]  clean started ... 
[13:56:46]  clean finished in 1 ms 
[13:56:46]  copy started ... 
[13:56:46]  deeplinks started ... 
[13:56:46]  deeplinks finished in 67 ms 
[13:56:46]  transpile started ... 
[13:56:51]  transpile finished in 5.18 s 
[13:56:51]  preprocess started ... 
[13:56:51]  preprocess finished in 1 ms 
[13:56:51]  webpack started ... 
[13:56:51]  copy finished in 5.53 s 

michaels-macbook-pro:ionic-app michael$
```

**ionic info**

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.15.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.15.2
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
Cordova Platforms  : browser 5.0.1 ios 4.5.2
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
Node       : v8.6.0
npm        : 5.3.0 
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.0.1 Build version 9A1004
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

**ionic serve -verbose**

```
[DEBUG] Reason for not using local CLI: LOCAL_CLI_NOT_FOUND
[DEBUG] CLI flags: { interactive: true, confirm: false }
[DEBUG] { cwd: '/Users/michael/IdeaProjects/dercampus/app', local: false, binPath: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic', libPath: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/dist/index.js' }
[DEBUG] Daemon found (pid: 777)
```

Comment: `ionic info` ....?

Comment: @Sampath updated

Comment: Can you close the VS code completely and start it again?

Comment: @Sampath what do I mean by that?

Comment: Maybe you have more than 1 live server running. So kill them all and start it again.

Comment: @Sampath Oh yeah I think that's the case! How can I get the PID of the process and kill it?

Comment: Are you using `VS code` for developing?

Comment: @Sampath I'm using IntelliJ

Comment: Try closing all the instances of `IntelliJ` and start only 1 and do `ionic serve` again. With `VS code` I do like that.

Comment: @Sampath I did so, even restarted my Mac but still not working

Comment: Can you delete the `node_modules` folder and after that `npm i`

Comment: @Sampath Still unchanged

Comment: Can you run `ionic serve --verbose` and show all output details?

Comment: @Sampath updated

Answer (score 0):

**Error:**

> Reason for not using local CLI: LOCAL_CLI_NOT_FOUND

**Solution:**

```
npm install --save-dev --save-exact ionic@latest
```

Comment: Try `npm cache verify`